# shell script - need to send mail to particular id as per above output

Tags: linux, bash, shell, email

the below scripts am using for kill the PID who is running jobs in login node(eating more memory). as well the same time we need to send mail to user that your jobs killed with details. we are having list of user ID's & mail ID's

need help to send mail of particular user cc with admin mail id.

## example user id's & equivalent mail id's in file

```
apple       apple@gmail.com
mango       123@ymail.com
cat        cat@hotmail.com 
etc...
```

### sample script

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat test_script.in
#!/bin/sh
 output=$(ps axu | awk -v OFS='\t'  '{print $1, $2, $3, $4, $11}' | sort -k4 -nr |head -5| awk '{print $2}'| awk 'NR==2')
 user=$(ps axu | awk -v OFS='\t'  '{print $1, $2, $3, $4, $11}' | sort -k4 -nr |head -5| awk '{print $1}'| awk 'NR==2')
 details=$(ps axu | awk -v OFS='\t'  '{print $1, $2, $3, $4, $11}' | sort -k4 -nr |head -5| awk '{print $5}'| awk 'NR==2')
 kill -9 $output
 msg="Hi $user \n you are running jobs in login nodes\n process id $output \n job details $details"
 echo -e $msg |mail -s "pls dont run jobs in login nodes" XXXXXXX ## need help here###
[root@localhost ~]#}
```

could you pls help us,

Comment: First, please indent each line of the script 4 spaces so it shows up as a code block and is readable to people. Or, just accept the edits I made to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following for/done loop lines would work in both bash and sh to input the user/address lines one line at a time.

However, the user and email parsing lines I show here would only work in bash.  If you don't want to use bash, you could replace them with awk if you need to split the lines into user and e-mail.

```
for n in `cat emails_addresses.txt`; do {
     user=${n## *}
     email=${n%%* }
     # 
     # send e-mail using $email here
     #
done
```

If you use the string removal functions I showed in bash, notice the space before the * in one line and after the * in the other. The asterisk '*' is a wildcard symbol, and the lines above remove the indicated pattern from the beginning and end of the string respectively to yield user and e-mail.

Comment: Sorry, I had to go through a lot of edits to get that right, but it should get you on the right track.

Comment: OK, I'm done editing now. Good luck. Please up vote or accept answer if it works for you.